# Android performance with time related task

Tags: android, performance, listview, timertask

I want to create a listView full of items that has TextViews with values that decrease every second (such countdown). My question is what is the best way to make it?

I know that one Timer with TimerTask updating each row is better than one TimerTask for each row, but is there anything even better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option than using timer task is using handler. You can see why it is better [here](http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/). Visit [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for more details of handlers.

Comment: So I should use one Handler that has postDelayed runnable updating all my views?

Comment: yes, I'd use postDelayed() to schedule a Runnable (which reschedules itself via postDelayed() to create your timing loop), so you can avoid the implicit background thread involved in TimerTask.